# I need a step by step guide with demo web app on how to build a PHP & MySQL web app on IBM Bluemix?

Tags: php, ibm-cloud

I need a step by step guide with demo web app on how to build a PHP & MySQL web app on IBM Bluemix ?

I want to build a simple data management web app on IBM Bluemix . (uses PHP & MySQL) .

Please help .

Thank you !

Comment: Have you tried this - https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/04/06/from-workshop-to-production-in-under-a-day-migrating-a-php-app-to-bluemix/? Not exactly what you need but has enough information to get you started.

Comment: This question does not belong on StackOverflow. For guidelines on appropriate questions, please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

Here's one example of a web app combining PHP, MySQL and IBM Bluemix.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/library/mo-bluemix-php-nutritionix-angularjs/index.html